# How to get text around md-icon with angular material

Tags: angular-material

So thought I would create a menu using fancy round buttons in angular material. 
And the code is ridiculously simple

```
<md-button class="md-fab md-primary" md-theme="default" aria-label="Home">
    <md-icon md-svg-src=/images/icons/home.svg" class="svg-icon" ></md-icon>
</md-button>
```

This gives me a nice round button, with a picture of a house on it, very easy and ever so fancy. 
Then I thought, lets add some text around it, kind of underneath the ring just saying "Home" but bent along the ring.

I would have thought someone had already done this, but can't find any way as far as I can tell.
(Like Italy in this one http://www.dreamstime.com/stock-illustration-venice-italy-round-metal-icon-italian-flag-blue-ribbon-text-most-important-monuments-city-bell-tower-image59945795)

Comment: Might try to write something that does it for me, if I have the time, but found a possible solution (that would be a lot of manual mupping about) https://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/

Comment: While you can do it, the idea of using Angular Material is to follow the [Material Design specification](https://material.io/guidelines/), which doesn't have that kind of label.
I recommend you read the section on "FAB" buttons. You'll see there is much more to them than just being "fancy round buttons".